PHP Телеграм АПИ Получить посты с количеством просмотров
не могу никак найти информацию как получить посты и количество просмотров через PHP
Сейчас публикую посты с помощью CURL:
function sendTelegram($method, $response)
{
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/' . $method);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $response);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $res;
}

$resulttg = sendTelegram(
    'sendPhoto', 
    array(
    'chat_id' => $telegramchatid,
    'caption' => $message,
    'photo' => $photofortg,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'reply_markup' => json_encode(array('inline_keyboard' => $keyboardtg))
    )
);

тем самым я публикую фото с комментарием методом sendPhoto
не могу найти как обойти канал и просмотреть посты с количеством просмотров.

хочу получить пост по ID чата и ID поста посмотреть сколько просмотров и записать в файл ссылку на пост и количество просмотров. мне нужно найти метод который получает сообщение в канале по id

не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать... Возможно вам нужен TGStat API

никак, апи бота такое не поддерживает. ТГСтат в помощь
